# Snowflake can't union two queries with same amount of columns and datatypes

Tags: sql, union, snowflake-cloud-data-platform

Trying to combine results which are the following results on snowflake. I used SQL server before this and im confused that Snowflake can't use UNION statements? Has anyone with lots of Snowflake experience have a solution to this problem?

```
SELECT
    PARSE_JSON(extra[0]['party'])[0]['trait1'] AS Trait1,
    COUNT(Trait1) AS T1
FROM E_OT AS EOT
WHERE Trait1 != 'NULL'
GROUP BY Trait1
ORDER BY T1 DESC
 
UNION
 
SELECT
    PARSE_JSON(extra[0]['party'])[0]['trait2'] AS Trait2,
    COUNT(Trait2) AS T2
FROM E_OT
WHERE Trait2 != 'NULL'
GROUP BY Trait2
ORDER BY T2 DESC
```

[image]

Comment: try to explicit the type https://docs.snowflake.com/en/sql-reference/operators-query.html#union-all

Answer (score 2):

The ORDER BY clause should be at the end:

```
SELECT
    PARSE_JSON(extra[0]['party'])[0]['trait1'] AS Trait1,
    COUNT(Trait1) AS T1
FROM E_OT AS EOT
WHERE Trait1 != 'NULL'
GROUP BY Trait1
UNION
SELECT
    PARSE_JSON(extra[0]['party'])[0]['trait2'] AS Trait2,
    COUNT(Trait2) AS T2
FROM E_OT
WHERE Trait2 != 'NULL'
GROUP BY Trait2
ORDER BY T1 DESC
```

https://docs.snowflake.com/en/sql-reference/operators-query.html#general-syntax

Answer (score 0):

I think that what you are trying to do is simpler using `grouping sets`:

```
SELECT COALESCE(PARSE_JSON(extra[0]['party'])[0]['trait1'],
                PARSE_JSON(extra[0]['party'])[0]['trait2']
               ) AS Trait,
       COUNT(*) AS T1
FROM E_OT AS EOT
GROUP BY GROUPING SETS ( (PARSE_JSON(extra[0]['party'])[0]['trait1']),
                         (PARSE_JSON(extra[0]['party'])[0]['trait2'])
                       )   
ORDER BY T1 DESC;
```

I'm not sure what your `WHERE` clause is doing.  It should be returning an error unless there is a `TRAIT1` column in the data.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

SELECT TRAIT1, T1 FROM
(
SELECT PARSE_JSON(EXTRA[0]['PARTY'])[0]['TRAIT1'] AS TRAIT1,
COUNT(TRAIT1) AS T1
FROM E_OT AS EOT
WHERE TRAIT1 != 'NULL'
GROUP BY TRAIT1
ORDER BY T1 DESC
)

UNION

SELECT TRAIT2, T2 FROM
(   SELECT
PARSE_JSON(EXTRA[0]['PARTY'])[0]['TRAIT2'] AS TRAIT2,
COUNT(TRAIT2) AS T2
FROM E_OT
WHERE TRAIT2 != 'NULL'
GROUP BY TRAIT2
ORDER BY T2 DESC
)